# Connecting Database Error using Pentaho Metadata Editor

Tags: mysql

Error connecting to database [SampleData2] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Access denied for user 'uary'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

i can't connect to database using penataho metadata editor, how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your credentials are being rejected as having a bad username or password.

Verify that the account details are correct and that you can log in to the database using the credentials via the command line `mysql` client.